# Why aren't the text links and the icon links not vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: htm]
In the picture above, the icons and the text aren't lining up. The links at the left sit at the bottom, the icons look centred and the right links also look centred except for the **profile** identifier that sits at the bottom.

I tried fixing this using

```
align-items:center;
```

but it doesn't solve the problem.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="right-icons">
                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">face</i>profile</a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">notification_important</i></a>
                    <a href="#">Sign in</a>
                    <a href="#">Log in</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
</body>
```

css code:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    background-color:white;
}

.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

nav{
    background-color: #333;
}

nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav a:hover{
    background-color:#555;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
    nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    nav ul{
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a css property to the parent div containing the **i** tag.

You can easily fix this by giving the **a** tag that is wrapping it

`display: flex; 
align-items: center;`

So it would looks something like this

```
nav a{
text-decoration:none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
color:white;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!